# Mat-table header not full size

Tags: angular, mat-table

In my applications I use a lot the `mat-table` component from Angular Material. Until now I never notice any issue. But now I see that on some `mat-table` the header are not fully aligned with data and I can't find the reasons.

All my table are generated the same way. I try to reproduce it on stackblitz, but I can't manage to have the same behavior..

Here is a working one :
[image]

And here is a example of mat-header issue :
[image]

Do you have any clue of the possible issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Checked whether `td` have `padding` or `text-align: center`, Add your HTML and CSS here.

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630623/angular-mat-table-weird-alignment-with-cells-containing-long-strings